# Bounding error term in Lagrange Interpolation

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I've spent more time that I'd like to admit working out this bound.

Online, I've seen that the remainder $R(x) = f(x) - L(x)$ in Lagrange interpolation is bounded by

$$| R(x) | \leq \frac{(x_n - x_0)^{n + 1}}{(n + 1)!} \max_{x_0 \leq \xi \leq x_n} f^{(n + 1)} (\xi).$$

I've tried to prove it, but gotten nowhere. Here, $f$ is an $n + 1$ times continuously differentiable function on a compact interval $I$, and $L(x)$ is the interpolating polynomial of $f$ with respect to the $n + 1$ nodes $\lbrace x_0, \dots, x_n \rbrace \subset I$.

My approach was to note that by applying Rolle's theorem many times one can deduce that

$$R(x) = \frac{f^{(n + 1)} (\xi)}{(n + 1)!} \ell (x).$$

Where $\ell (x) = \prod_{0 \leq k \leq n} (x - x_k)$ and $x_0 \leq \xi \leq x_n$ is a point that depends on $x$. Now, I believe that the inequality above is proven if I can show that

$$| \ell (x) | \leq (x_n - x_0)^{n + 1}.$$

I tried to find the critical points of this polynomial, but this doesn't seem to work out.

Comment: @metamorphy it only states the result, not a proof.

Comment: @metamorphy that section only proves that form of the error, it doesn't prove the inequality I'm trying to get.

Comment: I've just noticed that you're asking a much simpler thing. For $x_0\leqslant x\leqslant x_n$ and $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$ you have $|x-x_k|\leqslant x_n-x_0$. This readily gives $|\ell(x)|=\prod_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}|x-x_k|\leqslant(x_n-x_0)^{n+1}$.